# Error: failed to download "eks/appmesh-controller"

Tags: amazon-web-services, servicemesh, aws-app-mesh

i am trying to install Appmesh using these steps: https://www.eksworkshop.com/advanced/330_servicemesh_using_appmesh/appmesh_installation/install_appmesh/

however when i am running this command:

```
helm upgrade -i appmesh-controller eks/appmesh-controller \
--namespace appmesh-system \
--set region=$AWS_REGION \
--set serviceAccount.create=false \
--set serviceAccount.name=appmesh-controller \
--set tracing.enabled=true \
--set tracing.provider=x-ray
```

i get this error :

> Error: failed to download "eks/appmesh-controller"

Any idea why its failing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it is because you need to add the *`eks-charts`* repo, try running the following command

```
helm repo add eks https://aws.github.io/eks-charts
```

you can find more details in the step by step guide.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/app-mesh/latest/userguide/getting-started-kubernetes.html